# I am trying to simplify a mysql query and am not having luck

Tags: mysql

This is my original query which works

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) AS 'count',
    USR.user_name, 
    IF(
        ((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(workorder_id) FROM mod_workorder_data WHERE status_id < 8 AND assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL) < 50),
        (50- ((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(workorder_id) FROM mod_workorder_data WHERE status_id < 8 AND assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL))),
        -((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / (SELECT  COUNT(workorder_id) FROM mod_workorder_data WHERE status_id < 8 AND assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL))
    ) AS 'weight'
FROM mod_workorder_data WRK
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data USR ON USR.user_id = WRK.assigned_user_id
WHERE 
    status_id < 8
    AND WRK.assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY USR.user_name
```

results in this:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| count | user_name | weight  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     7 | 1:1Sum    | 47.3384 |
|    47 | ahin      | 32.1293 |
|    19 | asutt     | 42.7757 |
|    26 | bwan      | 40.1141 |
|     4 | cperr     | 48.4791 |
|    41 | dbemo     | 34.4106 |
|    41 | derob     | 34.4106 |
|    38 | dmay      | 35.5513 |
|    39 | jsue      | 35.1711 |
|     1 | lmar      | 49.6198 |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

So I thought that the query could be simplified to reduce redundancy, so I came up with this:

```
SET @total := (SELECT COUNT(workorder_id) FROM mod_workorder_data WHERE status_id < 8 AND assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL);

SELECT 
    @countIds := COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) AS 'count',
    USR.user_name,
    IF(
        (@countIds * 100) / @total < 50,
        (50 - (@countIds * 100) / @total),
        -(@countIds * 100) / @total
    ) AS 'weight'
FROM mod_workorder_data WRK
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data USR ON USR.user_id = WRK.assigned_user_id
WHERE
    status_id < 8 
    AND WRK.assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY USR.user_name
```

Which results in this:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
| count | user_name | weight |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|     7 | 1:1Sum    |   NULL |
|    47 | ahin      |   NULL |
|    19 | asutt     |   NULL |
|    26 | bwan      |   NULL |
|     4 | cperr     |   NULL |
|    41 | dbemo     |   NULL |
|    41 | derob     |   NULL |
|    38 | dmay      |   NULL |
|    39 | jsue      |   NULL |
|     1 | lmar      |   NULL |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Can anyone possibly see the error in my ways?  I must have some logic wrong in the simplified query, but I cannot tell what??

I am using MySql version 5.5.32 on a Fedora 18 box if it makes much of a difference.

Thanks

Dan Bemowski

Comment: Have you tried throwing a EXPLAIN in front of the select statement? This has helped (saved) me a lot in the past.

Comment: I think you'd have more luck, if you actually described (in text) what you want do do, Dan.

Comment: I thought I did.  I am trying to simplify the top query.  The original query at the top gives me the correct results that I am looking for.  The bottom query is just supposed to be a simplified version of the top query.

Comment: if you need any help, try http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: show your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, use inline view rather `correlated subquery`:

```
SELECT COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) AS 'count',
    USR.user_name, 
    IF(
        ((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / tab_cnt.cnt < 50),
        (50- ((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / tab_cnt.cnt)),
        -((COUNT(WRK.workorder_id) * 100) / tab_cnt.cnt)
    ) AS 'weight'
FROM mod_workorder_data WRK LEFT JOIN mod_users_data USR ON USR.user_id = WRK.assigned_user_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(workorder_id) AS cnt
        FROM  mod_workorder_data WHERE status_id < 8 AND assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL
    ) AS tab_cnt
WHERE status_id < 8
    AND WRK.assigned_user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY USR.user_name;
```

Comment: @DanBemowski Sounds good. please feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: fairly new to stackoverflow.  I just checked the green checkmark next to it.  I am guessing to accept it that's all I have to do, correct?